# Conditional probability of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am given the following exercise, where I don't see how to do this

[image]

Here $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. The expectation value $E^x$ means that we take the expectation value w.r.t. a Brownian motion starting in $x$ instead of zero. $\theta_s$ maps a Brownian motion $B_t$ to $B_{t+s}.$

What I don't understand here is now how to use this Markov property.

I mean sure we have $P(\tau_{a+b}< \infty; \tau_a < \infty) = E(1_{\tau_{a+b}< \infty} ; \tau_a < \infty), $ but how can I apply then the Markov property to actually show this relation for the conditional probability?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $B(0)=0$. On $\{\tau_a<\infty\}$,

$$
\{\omega:\tau_{a+b}<\infty\}=\{\omega: \tau_{a+b}-\tau_a<\infty\}=\{\omega: \tau_{a+b}\circ \theta_{\tau_a}<\infty\}.
$$

Thus,

$$
\mathbb{E}_0\left[1\{\tau_{a+b}<\infty \}\times 1\{\tau_a<\infty\}\right]
$$
$$=\mathbb{E_0}\left[\mathbb{E_0}[1\{\tau_{a+b}<\infty\}\circ \theta_{\tau_a}\mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}]\times1\{\tau_a<\infty\}\right]
$$
$$=\mathbb{E_0}\left[\mathbb{E_{B(\tau_a)}}[1\{\tau_{a+b}<\infty\}]\times1\{\tau_a<\infty\}\right]
$$
$$
=\mathbb{E_0}\left[\mathbb{E_0}[1\{\tau_{b}<\infty\}]\times1\{\tau_a<\infty\}\right]=P_0\{\tau_b<\infty\}P_0\{\tau_a<\infty\},
$$

and

$$
P_0\{\tau_{a+b}<\infty\mid \tau_a<\infty\}
$$
$$=\mathbb{E}_0\left[1\{\tau_{a+b}<\infty \}\times 1\{\tau_a<\infty\}\right] / P_0\{\tau_a<\infty\}=P_0\{\tau_b<\infty\}.
$$